# How does ScrollView work when wrapping a ZStack?

Tags: swiftui

In the code below, firstScrollProxy does not work, while secondScrollViewProxy does. I don't understand why.

The only solution I found, was to give some id to the overlay, and scroll to that. However that causes other issues for my code, and I'd rather avoid such workarounds.

I played with fixedSize() for the ZStack items, but that didn't help either.

Laying out the items vertically has the same issue, while a VStack works.

The anchor is optional, but trying different anchors does reveal the fact that the scroll view behaves as if the width of the items are the same as the entire scrollable area.

[image: The result of scrollTo:17]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        let numItems: Int = 100
        let itemWidth = 60.0
        let itemHeight = 100.0
        
        VStack(spacing: 4) {
            
            Spacer()
            
            ScrollViewReader { firstScrollProxy in
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    ZStack {
                        ForEach(0..<numItems, id:\.self) { x in
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(Color.purple)
                                .frame(width: itemWidth - 2, height: itemHeight)
                                .overlay {
                                    Text("\(x)")
                                }
                                .position(x: Double(x) * itemWidth + itemWidth / 2.0, y: itemHeight / 2.0)
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(width: Double(numItems) * itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                        firstScrollProxy.scrollTo(17, anchor: .center)
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(8)
            .background(Color(white: 0.2))
            
            Color.clear.frame(height: 10)
            
            ScrollViewReader { secondScrollProxy in
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    HStack(spacing: 2) {
                        ForEach(0..<numItems, id:\.self) { x in
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(Color.blue)
                                .frame(width: itemWidth - 2, height: itemHeight)
                                .overlay {
                                    Text("\(x)")
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(height: itemHeight)
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                        secondScrollProxy.scrollTo(17, anchor: .center)
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(8)
            .background(Color(white: 0.25))
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(.black)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ZStack` doesn't know about the effect of the `position` modifier. `ZStack` just assumes all of its children are piled up on top of each other, since that's how it lays them out. So when the `ZStack`'s parent `ScrollView` asks the `ZStack` for its size, the `ZStack` reports a size that is the maximum width and height of any of its children, without accounting for the side-by-side layout you have manually implemented.

Comment: That's helpful! Thank you! 

So is there any way to scroll to an id then?

Answer (score 0):

Given Rob's answer, the solution is actually to use the anchor to calculate the the position to scroll to. E.g.

```
ZStack {
  // ...
} 
.id("zstack")
.onTapGesture {
  .withAnimation {
      let x = position_of_17 / width_of_zstack
      firstScrollProxy.scrollTo("zstack", anchor: UnitPoint(x: x, y: 1.0))
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a better workaround, if anyone should have this problem. Simply embed a HStack with a width equal to the ZStack in which you can add invisible elements with the ids and the location that you need to scroll to.

In my case this is acceptable, I only ever need to programmatically scroll to 1 element, and switching to an actual HStack view for my content would not make sense for my use case.

```
ZStack {

    // Content

    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        Color.clear
            .frame(width: targetX, height: 1)
        Color.clear
            .frame(width: itemWidth, height: 1)
            .id("target")
        Color.clear
            .frame(width: totalWidth - targetX - itemWidth, height: 1)
    }

}

func scrollToTarget() {
  scrollProxy.scrollTo("target", anchor: anchor)
}
```